# How To Fix Windows Calculator Numbers Display?

Tags: windows-10, display, fonts, themes, calculator

When I open windows calculator it appears like this:

[image]

If I changed to the dark theme everything seems OK.

I have not changed Windows themes or display settings.

I tried:
1- Resetting the Calc app.
2- Restart windows (cold and normal).
3- Resetting Windows Fonts.

Among many other things, I can't remember them now.

I looked on the Internet and SO for days without luck.

Recently I discovered that other windows app have the same problem of disappearing some text. For example the Recorder app.

My Windows 10 64-bit is up to date as of 05/03/2023.

[image]

**So, How to Fix it?**

Any ideas?

*Note: When I click on a button the text appears, and once I release it the text disappears again.*

Comment: Did you check different compositions in settings?

Comment: if you mean calc setting it is the theme only (dark, light). If you refer to the windows settings, then what compositions you are referring to?

Comment: Windows settings. You can search for "compositions" there. Unless they're called something different in English, then look for a tab under Personalization.

Comment: apparently, they are. Any how, I tried every thing there.

Comment: And no luck I assume? Is calculator app itself up-to-date in Microsoft Store, what's the version? Which other apps exactly have this problem? Do you see it in any non-WIndows app?

Answer (score 1):

**(1) Run DISM / SFC:**

> (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
>
> (2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
>
> (3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
>
> (4) SFC /SCANNOW
>
> (5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

**(2) If DISM fails, run Windows 10 Repair Install**

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

Hopefully 1 or 2 will fix this.

**If 1 and 2 fail, reinstall Windows 10**

If not and there are still issues, there is more serious OS damage and / or you have a damaged Windows User Account.

In either case, the best way forward is to back everything up and re-install Windows 10

You may also choose to just live with the problem.

Comment: Thank you, but I do not want to start with the heavy weapons, nor with the mass destruction ones. :) Let us see if somebody experienced the same thing and had a better, simpler, and neater solution first. Otherwise, surgery it is.

Comment: DISM is simple to run, Repair Install, Keep Everything is also simple to run and not in any way heavy or invasive. That is a popular myth. Start with 1 and 2 (easy) and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Try as I suggested. I have a machine that is older, was runner Windows 11 Insider, ran out of breath and I backpedaled to Windows 10 a couple of weeks ago. Tonight I discovered Search was not working. I ran DISM and SFC and Search working on restart.   My suggestions come from experience

Comment: I already ran 1 and 2 no luck. I'll try later sfc and see.

Comment: I tried 1-5 and surprisingly it did not work. I do not want to take more time-consuming solutions right now. I think I will work around using the dark mode for the calc right now until I either have time to repair/reinstall windows or wait for the next windows major update. or maybe someone comes up with a magic trick before that. thanks anyway.

Comment: There is something wrong with your OS. You should definitely try the Repair and if your User Profile is damaged you may be looking at rebuilding.

Comment: @Shadi a key and basic function of your OS is broken. The suggestions by John ARE the simplest and the most effective means of resolving core OS issues like this.

Comment: It seems so. however, I do not need an immediate fix as big as reinstalling the OS. All previous steps had not worked. so, I have to wait either for a major windows upgrade and see if it would fix the issue, or wait for someone who could fix it with a simple trick that may be has nothing to do with OS directly like another app affecting the calc and whatsoever it could be. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: If all the previous steps did not work, a Windows Feature Upgrade likely will not fix the issue (it might - <20% but probably not > 80%)

Comment: I should note that there are not likely many more feature updates for Windows 10. Just 2 years left and it will be gone.